# I don't understand why the value of a is not being incremented in this given program

Tags: java

```
import java.lang.System; 
public class Sync
{ 
    int a=0;
    public void increment()
    {
        a++;
    }  
    public void result() 
    { 
    System.out.println("The value of a is:"+a); 
    }
}  
public class A extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {  
      Sync b=new Sync();
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<=1000;i++) 
        {
            b.increment();
        } 
    }
}
public class MainSync 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {  
      Sync c=new Sync(); 
    int i;
       A x=new A();
       x.start();
        c.result();
    }
}
```

In this program I created a thread which is responsible for incrementing the value of a and then the main thread prints the result,I don't understand what's wrong here and please help me fix this

Comment: `c` and `b` are different instances.

Comment: Please try to talk through the intended logic of your program. Start with: how many instances of the `A` class do you expect to be created? Do you expect those instances to use the same `a` field, or a separate one for each instance? Why?

Comment: But I am not able to understand what is to be done here

Comment: You have two instances of class `Sync`. One in the class `MainSync` and another in class `A`. When you start the instance `x` of the class `A` it calls the `increment` method of the instance `b`. However, you are checking the result in the instance `c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68767825/3788176) doesn't use threads correctly: because it doesn't override `Thread.run()`, starting the thread is a no-op; and invoking `x.run(c);` is executing the method on the main thread, rather than in the separate thread.

The `Sync` object should be passed as a constructor parameter.

An additional point not mentioned in other answers is that you need to wait for the Thread to finish: otherwise, even if using the same Sync instance, `c.result();` might execute before the thread runs, meaning zero would still be printed.

More specifically than just waiting for the thread to finish (e.g. via a sleep), you need to wait *and* ensure visibility of the actions done in the thread. The easiest way to ensure both of these is to use `x.join();`.

```
class Sync {
  int a = 0;

  public void increment() {
    a++;
  }

  public void result() {
    System.out.println("The value of a is:" + a);
  }
}

class A extends Thread {
  private final Sync b;

  A(Sync b) {
    this.b = b;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      b.increment();
    }
  }
}

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sync c = new Sync();
    A x = new A(c);
    x.start();
    x.join();
    c.result();
  }
}
```

Additionally, it is not a good practice to extend `Thread` directly: make `A` implement `Runnable` instead, and pass to the `Thread` constructor:

```
class A implements Runnable { ... }

// In main.
A a = new A(c);
Thread x = new Thread(x); // instead of A x = new A();
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` is a member variable of the class `Sync`.
Every time you do `new Sync()` you create a new instance (aka object) of that class and each instance will have its own member `a`.

I added some comments to your main method here:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {  
    Sync c = new Sync();   // c is a new instance

    A x = new A();         // x will create a new instance when started
    x.start();             // the thread creates another instance internally

    c.result();            // call result of the c instance => 0
}
```

As you can see there is nothing happening with your instance `c`. It is just created and the result method is called. The thread stuff has nothing to do with it because it creates its own instance of the class Sync.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is this:

```
class Sync
{
int a=0;
public void increment()
{
    a++;
}
public void result()
{
    System.out.println("The value of a is:"+a);
}
}

class A extends Thread
{
public void run(Sync b)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<1000; i++)
    {
        b.increment();
    }
    b.result();
}
}

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Sync c=new Sync();
    A x=new A();
    x.start();
    x.run(c);
}
}
```

Comment: probably an easier way to create this scenario but it's my first thought of it.

Comment: Please explain *why* this is what OP probably wants: what did you change, why does this fix it.

Comment: Also, I don't think this is what OP should want. You're not actually using the thread in a meaningful way: you're not overriding `Thread.run()`, so starting it is an effective no-op, and you end up running it on the main thread via the call to `run(c)`.

Comment: changed it to x.run(c) which uses the specifc a of Sync c, also used the result method in his Thread.run. So by these changes he actually uses Sync c.a and not a newly created Sync's a

Comment: Well he marked it as the answer he wanted, so I guess it is what he wanted? Please share your answer if you have a better idea.

Comment: it's entirely possible that OP doesn't understand what this code does.

Comment: most likely, but it is not my decision whether he comprehends what I've told him, I provided the answer, a bit of explanation and encourage other to provide their solution if they think it makes more sense, should be enough?

Comment: I can't see any explanation in your answer. See my answer to see what I mean about your use of threads.

Comment: Explanation in comments after you prompted me to, already looked at your answer and concluded that's better and where I went wrong, hence the upvote. EDIT: deleted my upvote when you edited your answer, did it again

Comment: don't put explanation in comments: they are liable to be deleted. Edit your answer to add salient points of the explanation.